# Why does du report different sizes for the same directory?

Tags: linux, bash

```
$ pwd
/

$ du -hs *
0       bin
8.2M    boot
82M     dev
23M     etc
0       lib
0       lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
0       misc
4.0K    mnt
0       net
106M    opt
44K     root
414M    run
0       sbin
4.0K    srv
0       sys
1.3G    usr
36M     var

$ du -hs var
118M    var
```

Why is the same directory reporting two different sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might notice that `dev` reports a large size, which when added to `var` produces the same as `var` by itself (82+36=118).  Normally `/dev` would be almost empty of space, consisting solely of directories and special files.

Perhaps there's some filesystem (or large hard-linked file) mounted in both which `du -sh *` factors out.

Comment: Ah yes, that was exactly it.